# How to pass environment variables to Dockerfile for db?

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I created api with node, express and postgres and i dockerized it, and now everything works.

But I was asked to do this in Dockerfile: "accepts database as an environment variable".

How i need to do that?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.12.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./ 
RUN npm install
COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: sh -c "npm start"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    working_dir: /app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://root:password@db:5432/chargeflow
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=chargeflow
    volumes:
      - ./db/data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't usually configure the database location in a Dockerfile, since both the location and credentials can vary if you run the image in different environments.  The environment-variable setting in the `docker-compose.yml` looks right; are you having trouble using it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don’t have problem using it, but when someone else will use my docker image, the DB will run fine? The person wont have to modify the credentials?

Comment: In the `docker-compose.yml` file they'll probably want to adjust the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` to something stronger and the corresponding password in the `DATABASE_URL` to match, but they should be able to reuse the _image_ as is.

Comment: Got you. So i did the configuration as they expected?